# Convert JSON string with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, type-conversion

I have a JS string like this (got from AJAX API call)

```
  {"Task":"Hours per Day","Slep":22,"Work":25,"Watch TV":15,"Commute":4,"Eat":7,"Bathroom":17}
```

I want to convert it into this format-

```
  [["Task", "Hours per Day"], ["Work", 11], ["Eat", 2], ["Commute", 2], ["Watch TV", 2], ["Sleep", 7]]
```

With the help of JS and jQuery.

Is there any way?

Comment: Already answered - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
// Parse your string into an object
var obj = JSON.parse(json); 

var array = [];

// Iterate on your object keys
for (var key in obj) {
    array.push([key, obj[key]]);
}

// Convert array into a JSON
json = JSON.stringify(array);
```

If you want to support old browsers, the `for (var key in obj)` may not work. You can also do like this if you want :

```
// Parse your string into an object
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

var array = [],
    keys = Object.keys(obj);

// Iterate on your object keys
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
    var key = keys[i];
    array.push([key, obj[key]]);
}

// Convert array into a JSON
json = JSON.stringify(array);
```